# Regex to accept only letters followed by comma

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to restrict the user input to the format like "wordA,wordB,wordC,wordD,wordE...". It must start with word(not case sensitive) and end with word as well, only one comma is accepted between each word. So it should be something like this:

```
   Match match = Regex.Match(tbx.text, @"//expression here",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
    //do sth
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: `String.Split` with simple check for each word may be easier to read/implement.... Also if you are trying to parse CSV - regular expressions are not really best tool - consider existing CSV parsers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the input is a list of words that allows for a single word (i.e. no comma) as well.

```
^[a-z]+(?:,[a-z]+)*$
```

Since, you're already using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` there's no need to define the class like `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have another scenario which only allow user to input words, commas and spaces, something like "Cloud computing, or the cloud, is .." What modification should I make based on your solution?

Comment: Add `\s` to allow whitespace. Use `[a-z\s]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^[0-9-]*$");
```

The `^` means that the match should start at the beginning of the input, the `$` that it should end at the end of the input.

The `*` means that (only) 0 or more numbers or dashes should be there (use + instead for 1 or more).

Comment: This would exclusively match numbers. OP wants to match on words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+,?)+[a-zA-Z]$
```

From beginning to end, must start with a letter, possibly followed by a comma (for single word entries), and can repeat any number of times; also, must end in a letter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have another scenario which only allow user to input words, commas and spaces, something like "Cloud computing, or the cloud, is .." What modification should I make based on your solution?

Comment: just add `\s`: `^([a-zA-Z\s]+,?)+[a-zA-Z]$`